# parseDate in Quicksight giving me an error

Tags: string, date, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

I am trying to use a calculated field and the parseDate function to convert a string to a date. The data format of the string I am trying to convert is as follows:

2023-02-13T22:46:15.000Z

I have tried both the following formulas while creating a calculated field in Quicksight but both give me an error.

parseDate({field_name}, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ')

parseDate({field_name}, 'yyyy-MM-ddTkk:mm:ss.SSSZ')

Answer (score 0):

You can see supported date formats here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-date-formats.html

Notice that T is supposed to be wrapped inside 'T'